# read a line of integers from written file? C programming

Tags: c, integer, eof, scanf

**I'm still fairly new to C and this is a beginner question. I am trying to read a line of integers separated by a whitespace from a file that I have already written to, but it is not working. When I try to print the integers to screen, I get -1. I'm not sure why this is happening:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
//create an array of characters
char str1[10];
//ask the user to enter a file name
printf("Enter a file name\n");
//str1 holds the address of the file name user enters
scanf("%s", str1);

FILE *fp;

fp = fopen(str1, "w+");
//write integer values to created file, separated by a space
fprintf(fp, "%d", 2);
fprintf(fp,"%c", ' ');
fprintf(fp, "%d", 4);
fprintf(fp,"%c", ' ');
fprintf(fp, "%d", 5);
fprintf(fp, "%c", ' ');
fprintf(fp, "%d", 7);
fprintf(fp, "%c", ' ');
fprintf(fp,"%d", 9);

int number;
int counter, c=0;
//if nothing is in file, then print error statement
if (fp==NULL){
    printf("File cannot be read");
}
c = fscanf(fp, "%d", &number);

while (c !=EOF){
    counter++;
    c = fscanf(fp, "%d", &number);
    printf("%d",c);
}
fclose(fp);

}
```

How do I properly print the integers to screen? (count is being used later to calculate the average, and I am originally asking the user to enter a file name that will have integers written to a file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems:

1. After writing to the file the position is at the end of the file. Need to `rewind` to start back at the beginning of the file before reading it.
2. The `printf` should print `number` not `c`.
3. The `printf` should be placed before the `fscanf` in the loop. Otherwise the first number is missed and the last print is for the `fscanf` that has returned `EOF` (ie, `number` not valid for that last case).